# How to Delete a Project in Android Studio IDE 1.02?

Tags: android, android-studio

I used Eclipse for Android project, and now I switch to Android Studio which is pretty nice, but is't different a lot from Eclipse. I don't know how to delete project from Android Studio?

Comment: I have just found useful article posted here: http://tekeye.biz/2014/delete-project-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

There are many guides on intenret.

If you can not understand the tutorial you should watch some videos like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lvFCRl_zxsw

Bye :)